# Bouncing ball braking bricks game, fails to bounce of a brick

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So my problem is that the ball just passes trough the bricks, nothing happens. I will put the whole code in jsbin, here I post only the piece that is not working. As you can see, I got a bouncing ball, a racket, bricks and an animationFrame function.

```
for (var i in bricks) {
    if (!bricks[i].isDestroyed) {

        if (
            (this.y + this.radius == bricks[i].y - bricks[i].height)
            && (this.x >= bricks[i].x)
            && (this.x <= bricks[i].x + bricks[i].width)
        ) {
            bricks[i].isDestroyed = true;
            destroyedBrick = true;
            this.direction.y = "up";
            ctx.clearRect(bricks[i].x, bricks[i].y, bricks[i].width, bricks[i].height);
        }

        if (
            (this.y - this.radius == bricks[i].y)
            && (this.x >= bricks[i].x)
            && (this.x <= bricks[i].x + bricks[i].width)
        ) {
            bricks[i].isDestroyed = true;
            destroyedBrick = true;
            this.direction.y = "down";
            ctx.clearRect(bricks[i].x, bricks[i].y, bricks[i].width, bricks[i].height);
        }

        if (
            (this.x - this.radius == bricks[i].x)
            && (this.y - this.radius <= bricks[i].y)
            && (this.y - this.radius >= bricks[i].y - bricks[i].height)
        ) { 
            bricks[i].isDestroyed = true;
            destroyedBrick = true;
            this.direction.x = "left";
            ctx.clearRect(bricks[i].x, bricks[i].y, bricks[i].width, bricks[i].height);
        }

        if (
            (this.x == bricks[i].x + bricks[i].width)
            && (this.y - this.radius <= bricks[i].y)
            && (this.y - this.radius >= bricks[i].y - bricks[i].height)
        ) {
            bricks[i].isDestroyed = true;
            destroyedBrick = true;
            this.direction.x = "right";
            ctx.clearRect(bricks[i].x, bricks[i].y, bricks[i].width, bricks[i].height);
        }
    }
}
```

Jsbin code: http://jsbin.com/eZOxusaQ/1/watch?html,js,output

Comment: This does not describe how ball movement works, only how ball-brick collisions work. There is not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Well that's why I posted jsbin. It's not complicated, I can't really make it complicated :D . Basically when ball reaches some coordinates for x and y (end of canvas, racket, hopefully bricks) it changes its x and y "directions" and starts moving not by for example x= +1 but by x= -1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the collision code is using == on some of the checks when you probably want an inequality. So my guess is the ball is stepping over that exact position, resulting in the other checks being skipped. Switch all comparisons to be >= or <= as appropriate and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed your code.

Basically, I changed the `==` to `<=`, as the ball will never hit this EXACT spot. Furthermore I added a `break` inside each of the `if`-conditions to quit the check when one brick got hit, as you want the ball to jump off and not to exterminate a whole row.

```
for (var i in bricks) {
    if (!bricks[i].isDestroyed) {                   
        if ((this.y + this.radius <= bricks[i].y - bricks[i].height) && (this.x >= bricks[i].x) && (this.x <= bricks[i].x + bricks[i].width)) {
            bricks[i].isDestroyed = true;
            destroyedBrick = true;
            this.direction.y = "up";
            ctx.clearRect(bricks[i].x, bricks[i].y, bricks[i].width, bricks[i].height);
            break;
        }
        if ((this.y - this.radius <= bricks[i].y) && (this.x >= bricks[i].x) && (this.x <= bricks[i].x + bricks[i].width)) {
            bricks[i].isDestroyed = true;
            destroyedBrick = true;
            this.direction.y = "down";
            ctx.clearRect(bricks[i].x, bricks[i].y, bricks[i].width, bricks[i].height);
            break;
        }
        if ((this.x - this.radius <= bricks[i].x) && (this.y - this.radius <= bricks[i].y) && (this.y - this.radius >= bricks[i].y - bricks[i].height)) {                       
            bricks[i].isDestroyed = true;
            destroyedBrick = true;
            this.direction.x = "left";
            ctx.clearRect(bricks[i].x, bricks[i].y, bricks[i].width, bricks[i].height);
            break;
        }
        if ((this.x <= bricks[i].x + bricks[i].width) && (this.y - this.radius <= bricks[i].y) && (this.y - this.radius >= bricks[i].y - bricks[i].height)) {                       
            bricks[i].isDestroyed = true;
            destroyedBrick = true;
            this.direction.x = "right";
            ctx.clearRect(bricks[i].x, bricks[i].y, bricks[i].width, bricks[i].height);
            break;
        }                  
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
You *will* get a problem when your ball hits an "inner brick", for example a brick one row above a row with still bricks left. As your ball will exterminate these bricks with your current conditions, as the coordinates of the ball will be smaller than the coordinates of your brick. But that's more a general problem of your logic. You'll need to include more checks for this one. ;)